# Improve multiple api performance in android using coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

I have to show a progress loader unless all api fetched whether fail or passed. I write below code to do this

```
viewModelScope.launch {
            val requestStateFlows = arrayListOf(
                bookingEventApiRequestStateFlow,
                orderPickupsApiRequestStateFlow,
                bonusGiftApiRequestStateFlow,
                personalOffersApiRequestStateFlow,
                favoriteOffersApiRequestStateFlow,
            ).filterNotNull()
            combine(
                requestStateFlows
            ) { requests ->
                _isDynamicDataLoaded.value =
                    requests.all { it?.status == ApiRequestStatus.COMPLETED } 
            }.collect()
        }
```

AFter all api data is populated.

```
private fun setObservers() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                viewModel.isDynamicDataLoaded.collect { allDataLoaded ->

                    binding.progressBar.visibility = if(allDataLoaded) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
                    if (allDataLoaded) {
                        combine(viewModel.personalOffers,viewModel.favoriteOffersLiveData){ personalOfferz, favouriteOfferz ->
                            personalOffersModelList.clear()
                            personalOffersModelList.addAll(personalOfferz.map {
                                PersonalOfferModel(it)
                            })
                            updateTabCounter(SwimLaneItemType.PERSONAL_OFFERS,personalOffersModelList.size)

                            favoriteOffersModelList.clear()
                            favoriteOffersModelList.addAll(favouriteOfferz.map {
                                FavoriteOfferModel(Product.mapFromDB(it))
                            })
                            updateTabCounter(SwimLaneItemType.FAVOURITE_OFFERS,favoriteOffersModelList.size)
                            val mAll = personalOfferz.size + favouriteOfferz.size
                            updateTabCounter(SwimLaneItemType.ALL,mAll)

                            selectTabAt(selectedTab)
                        }.collect {}

                        combine(viewModel.orderPickupsFlow,viewModel.bonusGiftsFlow){ orderPickUps,bonusGiftz ->

                            orderPickupsList.clear()
                            orderPickupsList.addAll(orderPickUps)

                            bonusGiftsList.clear()
                            bonusGiftsList.addAll(bonusGiftz)
                            updateOrderPickUpItemView()
                        }.collect {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> Is there any improvement are from where my api populate a little bit fast

I am calling all my api using **WorkerManager** like

```
WorkManager.getInstance(it).beginUniqueWork("store_mode_data_task", ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, workers).enqueue()
```

Do my combine function work together or it may tooking time?